# Is ASP.NET MVC 5 released or not?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework) - asp.NET MVC 5 was released on 17th October 2013.

However on the [ASP Website](http://www.asp.net/mvc) I can't see where to download the package.

When I try to create a new Project in VS 2013 - I can only choose asp.NET MVC 4.

How can I install MVC 5 ?

Comment: what is your target framework for the project created in VS 2013?

Comment: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [nuget site](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc):

Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 5.0.0

To install Microsoft ASP.NET MVC, run the following command in the [Package Manager Console](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console)

> PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc

Comment: so, no way to install ASP.NET MVC 5 like previous versions (to select when create web-app, in control panel -> program list)?

Comment: In Visual Studio 2013. Create a new project using the ASP.NET Web Application template. It is residing in File => New => Project... => Installed => Templates => Visual C# => Web => ASP.NET Web Application.

Comment: No need to install any Nuget Packages; as @Martin4ndersen said, create a project by selecting ASP.NET Web Application and under that select MVC. This automatically creates MVC 5 project.

Answer (score 6):

In Visual Studio 2013, the MVC project wizard was merged with the ASP.NET Web Application Wizard. When you target .NET 4.5, select the ASP.NET project. You will be presented with a new wizard that will allow you to select a base template and then customize it further by adding support for Web API or MVC. It also allows you to customize the authentication/authorization model you wish to use in your application.

The MVC 4 wizard is still present under the VS 2012 node in the New Project dialog.

Runtime packages for MVC 5, Web API 2, and Web Pages 3 were published to nuget.org, so you can upgrade existing projects.

You can also download a separate installer for Visual Studio 2012 that will allow you to create an MVC 5 and Web API 2 project, albeit empty. Once you have the project created you will be able to add views and controllers using the new scaffolding. The download for the Visual Studio 2012 support can be found at [here](https://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/webpi.ashx/getinstaller/WebNode11Pack.appids)

Thanks,
Jacques

Answer (score 0):

You can download it directly from this link:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc5

Answer (score 0):

You can find all versions of latest MVC from below nuget

http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc